# Is there a way to get OAuth 2.0 token directly with CURL?

Tags: php, authentication, curl, token, access-token

I want to get an access token to call to Google Directory API. I have seen several posts with PHP Curl code, but everytime there has to be a human action to permit access before you get the access token. Is there a way to make a CURL request and get the access token directly?

This is my code so far:

```
 define("CALLBACK_URL", "http://localhost/los/index");
define("AUTH_URL", "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
 define("ACCESS_TOKEN_URL", "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token");
define("CLIENT_ID", "**.apps.googleusercontent.com");
 define("CLIENT_SECRET", "**");
 define("SCOPE", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.device.chromeos"); 

function getToken(){
  $curl = curl_init();

  $params = array(
CURLOPT_URL =>  
ACCESS_TOKEN_URL."?"."&grant_type=authorization_code"."&client_id=". 
CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=". CLIENT_SECRET."&redirect_uri=". CALLBACK_URL,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_NOBODY => false, 
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
  "cache-control: no-cache",
  "Content-Length: 0",
  "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "accept: *",
      "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate",
    ),
  );

  curl_setopt_array($curl, $params);

   $response = curl_exec($curl);
   $err = curl_error($curl);
    echo $response;
  curl_close($curl);

 if ($err) {
echo "cURL Error #01: " . $err;
   } else {
$response = json_decode($response, true);    
if(array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) return $response;
if(array_key_exists("error", $response)) echo $response["error_description"];
echo "cURL Error #02: Something went wrong! Please contact admin.";
  } 
 }
```

When I run it I get this error message:

```
{ "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }Missing required parameter: codec
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just been through a similar problem with using PHP cURL to get an access token from the http code returned by the Google API after the user authorizes the consent screen. Here's my long-winded answer:

From least to most important: you should start by fixing the brackets after your if conditions:

```
    if (array_key_exists("access_token", $response)) {
      return $response
    } elseif (array_key_exists("error", $response)) {
      echo $response["error_description"];
      echo "cURL Error #02: Something went wrong! Please contact admin.";
    }
```

The error message "Missing required parameter: code" appears because you need to post the code that was returned in the url after the client authorizes your app. You'd do that by doing something like:

```
    CURLOPT_URL => ACCESS_TOKEN_URL."?"."&code=".$_GET['code']."&grant_type=authorization_code"."&client_id=".CLIENT_ID."&client_secret=". CLIENT_SECRET."&redirect_uri=".CALLBACK_URL,
```

To make it more semantic you'd define the $authorization code variable before that:

```
    $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];
```

Lastly, the most important part is that to get an Access Token from Google you need to used the cURL post method as shown in the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code

You can do that with PHP cURL with this command:

```
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

But then you need to break your URL into two parts: the host and the fields to be posted. To make it easier to read, you can setup your endpoint and the fields into variables:

```
    $endpoint = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';

    $fieldsToPost = array(
     // params for the endpoint
     'code' => $authorizationCode, //being that $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];
     'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
     'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
     'redirect_uri' => CALLBACK_URL,
     'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    );
```

Then you can use the $enpoint to set the url and http_build_query() to set up your fields. In the end, adapting your code to the code that worked for me would look something like this:

```
    function getToken() {

     $endpoint = 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token';

     $fieldsToPost = array(
      // params for the endpoint
      'code' => $authorizationCode, //being that $authorizationCode = $_GET['code'];
      'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
      'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
      'redirect_uri' => CALLBACK_URL,
      'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
     );

     $curl = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $endpoint);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fieldsToPost));
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE );   

     // get curl response, json decode it, and close curl
    $googleResponse = curl_exec($curl);
     $curl_error = curl_errno($curl);
     $googleResponse = json_decode( $googleResponse, TRUE );
     curl_close( $curl );

    return array( // return response data
      'url' => $endpoint . '?' . http_build_query( $params ),
      'endpoint' => $endpoint,
      'params' => $params,
      'has_errors' => isset( $googleResponse['error'] ) ? TRUE : FALSE, // b oolean for if an error occured
      'error_message' => isset( $googleResponse['error'] ) ? $googleResponse['error']['message'] : '', // error message
      'curl_error' => $curl_error, //curl_errno result
      'google_response' => $googleResponse // actual response from the call
     );
    }
```

To check the response you can use the following print function to see the response:

```
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
     $response = getToken();
     echo '<pre>';
     print_r($response);
     die();
    }
```

I know it's been a long time and you've probably found a workaround but I hope this is still useful for future projects. Cheers!